# How does an ideal generated by $(x^{2})$ in $Z[x]$?

Tags: ideals, principal-ideal-domains

I was just wondering whether there would exist an element $x^{-2}$ and how would the elements in general look like?

Comment: "How does an ideal generated by $(x^2)$"... *do what*?

Comment: Also: in what ring are we?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's all the polynomials in $\Bbb Z[x]$ with zero constant and $x$-term.

$x^{-2}$ is not a polynomial, so not an element of $\Bbb Z[x]$.

Answer (score 5):

The ideal generated by $x^2$ in $\Bbb Z[x]$ is the set of all polynomials which may be written as $x^2f(x)$ for some polynomial $f\in\Bbb Z[x]$. Specifically, if $g(x)=\sum_{j=0}^m a_jx^j$, then $g\in(x^2)$ if and only if $a_0=a_1=0$.